# How to update weights of a base Keras PointNet model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, regression, mlmodel

I trained a PointNet regression model and then saved it's weights by

```
model.save_weights('/home/rev9ai/aleef/Dainsta/model/beta_v0.weights.ckpt')
```

The saved files were

- beta_v0.weights.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
- beta_v0.weights.ckpt.index

Now I want to update a base PointNet model using these weights
Here is how the model was built using Tensorflow:

```
# Define the PointNet architecture for regression
def build_pointnet_regression_model(num_points=2048):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(num_points, 3))
    
    x = tnet(inputs, 3)
    x = conv_bn(x, 32)
    x = conv_bn(x, 32)
    x = tnet(x, 32)
    x = conv_bn(x, 32)
    x = conv_bn(x, 64)
    x = conv_bn(x, 64) #additional
    x = conv_bn(x, 64) #additional
    x = conv_bn(x, 512)
    x = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
    x = dense_bn(x, 256)
    # x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
    # x = dense_bn(x, 128)
    # x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)

    # Regression output layer
    outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="relu")(x)
    
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="pointnet_regression")
    return model

# Create the PointNet regression model
model = build_pointnet_regression_model(NUM_POINTS)

# Compile the model for regression
model.compile(
    loss="mean_absolute_error", 
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.1),
    metrics=["mean_absolute_error"],
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "update"?

Comment: Load, to be precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
model.load_weights('location/to/weights.ckpt')
```

That's how you load weights. Just build/ define the model as usual and then load pre-saved weights.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**